# How to find the minimum difference between numbers in a numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, spacing, minimum

I have a numpy array with samples which are the output of an experiment. The samples are all integers but I don't think that matters. Some values appear a few times in the array while some appear hundreds of times - the arrays can comprise 10,000 samples.

While the values look random, they have a minimum spacing. What I mean is that no two values are closer to each other than, for example, 27. So you might see 50 samples of value 999,027 in the array somewhere and you might see 120 samples of 999,054 but you would not see a single 999,036 sample value anywhere in the array. I need to check the array and establish what that minimum spacing is but very quickly if possible. You might call this the 'closest sample value distance'. I don't have to check every case, as you might imagine just checking a few samples, as long as they are ones that are close in value, tends to give you a good guess at what the minimum difference is.

Has anyone got a clever algorithm (using Python) that could fairly quickly find this closest minimum distance between any samples? The arrays can be large, as I said, and there are many tens of them to be checked each second.

Apologies that this is such a weird question. I hope that I have managed to explain it well enough.

Answer (score 2):

Since you have numpy arrays, numpy should speed this up, although there are probably more efficient implementations:

```
import numpy as np
from timeit import timeit

#Riccardo Bucco
def f1(lst):
    sorted_lst = sorted(set(lst))
    return min(n2 - n1 for n1, n2 in zip(sorted_lst, sorted_lst[1:]))

#numpy solution
def f2(arr):
    b = np.diff(np.sort(arr))
    return b[b>0].min()

ntime = 100 #number of test runs
nxd = 5000    #array length
nmax = 1000000

print(timeit(lambda: f1(np.random.randint(1, nmax, nxd)), number=ntime))
#0.347

print(timeit(lambda: f2(np.random.randint(1, nmax, nxd)), number=ntime))
#0.0327
    

ntime = 10 #number of test runs
nxd = 5000000    #array length
nmax = 100000000

print(timeit(lambda: f1(np.random.randint(1, nmax, nxd)), number=ntime))
#62.54

print(timeit(lambda: f2(np.random.randint(1, nmax, nxd)), number=ntime))
#5.46
```

Comment: Ah brilliant concept Riccardo. That is a great way of thinking about how to get an answer and minimising the processing time. So, the logic is to sort the list by value and then find the minimum difference between adjacent sorted samples. Good to see that numpy is efficient working this way. I didn't say but the samples are more likely to exhibit the minimum gap when they are lower values which makes it easier to use sampling to speed this up. Thank you.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to thank Mr T and Riccardo for the concept and execution - my mistake. Anyway, Mr T; I have used this now in the numpy version and it works perfectly thank you. The numpy one is really fast compared with what I had come up with. In addition, I think I will easily be able to speed it up too - not looking at the whole array for example but using a sample will probably work in practice for the data I have. Would recommend this approach for anyone with a similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can sort the unique elements of your array and then find the shortest distance between consecutive numbers:

```
def find_min_distance(lst):
    sorted_lst = sorted(set(lst))
    return min(n2 - n1 for n1, n2 in zip(sorted_lst, sorted_lst[1:]))
```

For example:

```
>>> lst = [6, 8, 1, 4, 9, 4, 8]
>>> find_min_distance(lst)
1
```

The complexity of this approach is O(nlogn), where n is the number of elements in your original array. You can't have a better complexity, unless you know in advance the range in which your numbers fall.